# Pairwise comparisons of a large amount of sorted arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Suppose I have `n` sorted integer arrays (`a_1`, ..., `a_n`, there may be duplicated elements in a single array), and `T` is a threshold value between 0 and 1. I would like to find all pairs of arrays the similarity of which is larger than `T`. The similarity of array `a_j` w.r.t. array `a_i` is defined as follows:

```
sim(i, j) = intersection(i, j) / length(i)
```

where `intersection(i, j)` returns the number of elements shared in `a_i` and `a_j`, and `length(i)` returns the length of array `a_i`.

I can enumerate all pairs of arrays and compute the similarity value, but this takes too much time for a large `n` (say `n=10^5`). Is there any data structure, pruning strategy, or other techniques that can reduce the time cost of this procedure? I'm using Java so the technique should be easily applicable in Java.

Comment: i think this lodash function can help you:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#difference

Comment: @DerHerrGammler Is there any solution based on Java?

Comment: To confirm: sim(i, j) != sim(j, i) if length(i) != length(j), correct? Just want to confirm you don't intend to use the max of these two lengths. E.g. if a_i = [0] and a_j = [0, 1, ..., 99] them sim(i, j) = 100% and sim(j, i) = 1%.

Comment: @Dave Yes. `sim(i,j)` is not necessarily the same as `sim(j,i)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are `(n^2 - n)/2` pairs of arrays. If `n=10^5`, then you have to compute the similarity of 5 billion pairs of arrays. That's going to take some time.

One potential optimization is to shortcut your evaluation of two arrays if it becomes clear that you won't reach T. For example, if T is 0.5, you've examined more than half of the array and haven't found any intersections, then it's clear that that pair of arrays won't meet the threshold. I don't expect this optimization to gain you much.

It might be possible to make some inferences based on prior results. That is, if `sim(1,2) = X` and `sim(1,3) < T`, there's probably a value of `X` (likely would have to be very high) at which you can say definitively that `sim(2,3) < T`.